# create a folder in google drive anomymously

Tags: php, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client

hi there i am using google drive as a storage space for my website.. soo i was wondering is there a way to create a folder in google drive anonymously using php.. i found these links to create a folder in google drive but they require authorization every time i want to create a new folder.

[Create a sub folder using google-drive-api and return the id with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19870859/create-a-sub-folder-using-google-drive-api-and-return-the-id-with-php)

[Error when creating google drive folder using sample PHP code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13642053/error-when-creating-google-drive-folder-using-sample-php-code)

basically i want something like anonymous upload but only this one will be creating folder anonymously. hope i made myself clear.

any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No its not possible (and doesnt make sense).
What you need is learn how to do the oauth flow to save a refresh token.
Your server uses that to deal with the permissions. The user never sees the permissions.